# Communication between two fluentd instances using http plugin fails with bad request

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I have a problem with communication between fluentds using http_out and http_in plugins. I have two kubernetes clusters and I want the fluentd-A in the first cluster to send it's logs to the fluentd-B in the second cluster. But when fluentd-A tries to send the logs it recieves:

```
#0 got unrecoverable error in primary and no secondary error_class=Fluent::UnrecoverableError error="400 Bad Request 400 Bad Request\n'json' or 'msgpack' parameter is required\n"
#0 bad chunk is moved to /tmp/fluent/backup/worker0/object_3ff8a73edae8/5a71a08ca19b1b343c8dce1b74c9a963.log
```

When I cat this file the logs in it has the following pattern:

```
{log: ...., ... other json fields... }
{log: ...., ... other json fields... }
{log: ...., ... other json fields... }
```

I think the problem is that the concatenation of json objects is not a json and that is why fluentd-B sends as response 400 Bad Request.

I have tested the fluentd-B with curl with the following requests and it works ok:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"foo":"bar"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://<fluentd-B-ip>:9880/app.log
curl -X POST -d 'json=[{"foo":"bar"},{"abc":"def"},{"xyz":"123"}]' http://<fluentd-B-ip>:9880/app.log
```

Could someone tell me how to pack the logs in the fluentd-A into a valid json? (It's not necessary to be json)

This is the config of the fluentd-A:

```
<match **>
  @type http

  endpoint http://<Fluentd-B-IP>:9880/api.log
  open_timeout 2
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>

<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>

<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_TAG'] || 'kubernetes.*'}"
  exclude_path "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH'] || use_default}"
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE'] || 'json'}"
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
  @id filter_kube_metadata
  kubernetes_url "#{ENV['FLUENT_FILTER_KUBERNETES_URL'] || 'https://' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST') + ':' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT') + '/api'}"
  verify_ssl "#{ENV['KUBERNETES_VERIFY_SSL'] || true}"
  ca_file "#{ENV['KUBERNETES_CA_FILE']}"
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type grep
  <regexp>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern /test/
  </regexp>
</filter>
```

This is the config of the fluentd-B:

```
<source>
  @type http
  port 9880
  bind 0.0.0.0
  body_size_limit 32m
  keepalive_timeout 10s
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>

</source>
```

I hope someone could help with this, I though that such basic setup should be easy but maybe I missed something important...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in fluentd github page the same question and it turns out the communication with http_in and http_out is not supported. They are used for communication with other types of components and forward_in and forward_out plugins are recommended for communication between fluentds.

This is the [link](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/3022) to my question.